# Can I change namespace of WCF ServiceContract interface without changing the service?

Tags: wcf, servicecontract

Is there a way to change the .NET namespace of a WCF ServiceContract Interface yet still make the WCF service backwards-compatible with clients that are using the old (identical except for namespace) ServiceContract?  For example, suppose I have (in vb.net):

```
Namespace MyCompany.MyPoorlyNamedProject
    <ServiceContract(Name:="ThingService")> _
    <CLSCompliant(True)> _
    Public Interface IThingService
        ...
    End Interface
EndNamespace
```

And I want to change that to

```
Namespace MyCompany.MyProject
    <ServiceContract(Name:="ThingService")> _
    <CLSCompliant(True)> _
    Public Interface IThingService
        ...
    End Interface
End Namespace
```

Without changing the service at all.

I tried just doing so, but my xsds referred to from the wsdl show the new namespace name, which seems to be an incompatibility.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As long as the name and (XML) namespace of your service contract don't change - sure! WCF services really don't care about the .NET internals of how they're implemented.

This works as long as the client side attaches to your service using the standard `Add Service Reference` method (interrogating the service's metadata to create a separate client-side proxy) - in that case, the client-side proxy has **no knowledge** of any service-side .NET namespaces... you can change those on the service side and redeploy your service files - the client will continue to work.

The only place you'll need to make an adjustment is in the config of your service side (in `web.config` if you're hosting in IIS, in your hoster's `app.config` otherwise):

- the `<service>` tag's `name=` attribute has the service class' fully qualified .NET type name (including .NET namespace)
- the `<endpoint>` tag's `contract=` attribute has the service contract's fully qualified .NET type name (including .NET namespace)

This doesn't work, obviously, if you share a common assembly with the service contract - in that case, the client side will be tied to the .NET namespace of those contract files in a common assembly and if those change, the client won't work anymore..

Comment: I'm not using "Add Service Reference"--it gave unexpected results - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294269/getting-bad-generated-code-from-update-service-reference .  Maybe this will work anyway?  I'll try it soon.

Comment: @Patrick Szalapski: well, in that case, you're probably sharing the contracts assembly between service and client, right?? In that case, **of course**, changing the namespaces on your service contract **will** affect the client - no way around it.

Comment: This [explanation](http://blog.rebuildall.net/2010/11/10/wcf_service_namespaces) clarified it for me.